# cost explorer in python-boto3 unknown service 'ce'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Good day, Recent AWS release API for know the billing information.

It is  available in all aws SDK (c#,python,php). I just tried a lambda function to update my database table with current cost of my all linked accounts. but mt lambda function doesn't work. it show the following error

> "Unknown service: 'ce'. Valid service names are: acm, apigateway, application-autoscaling, appstream, athena, autoscaling,etc "

my lambda code is :

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def lambda_handler(event, context):
client1 = boto3.client(
'ce',
aws_access_key_id=accesskey,
aws_secret_access_key=secretkey)
[referral link for client creation][1]
response = client1.get_cost_and_usage(
TimePeriod={
    'Start': startdate,
    'End': enddate
},
Granularity='MONTHLY',
Metrics=[
    'BlendedCost',
],
GroupBy=[
    {
        'Type': 'DIMENSION',
        'Key': 'LINKED_ACCOUNT'
    },
],
)

print response
```

Comment: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/311

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned in the Boto3 bugtracker](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1362) this might happen if you have updated your `boto3` without updating your `botocore`.

So I suggest to update `botocore` and retry:

```
pip install botocore --upgrade
```

or in some different way, depends on how you installed botocore in the first place.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but this is suitable for which is run in local or aws server. my question is how we fix it in lambda function. we just include at top of lambda function import boto3 or import botocore i tried both. but it still show the above error only, we din't install and update any package in AWS lambda , it is server-less infrastructure

Comment: @ArunKumar I see. I didn't know you were using AWS Lambda. You are right. My answer doesn't apply then.

Answer (score 0):

I think simply AWS Lambda team hasn't upgraded `botocore` to the newest version yet.
As the moment of writing this, the [docs for AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) mention 1.7.37 as current version of botocore:

> AWS SDK for Python 2.7 (Boto 3) version 3-1.4.7 botocore-1.7.37
>
> AWS SDK for Python 3.6 (Boto 3) version 3-1.4.7 botocore-1.7.37

And reading [the botocore changelog](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst) the oldest it mentions `ce` is 1.7.48:

> 1.7.48
>
> [...]
>
> api-change:ce: Update ce client to latest version

So my guess is - one AWS team hasn't picked up what some other team at AWS already had released.

You can contact AWS support or wait a few days. I'd guess.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has updated botocore (at least in eu-central-1) now:

Valid service names are: acm, alexaforbusiness, apigateway, application-autoscaling, appstream, appsync, athena, autoscaling, batch, budgets, **ce,** cloud9,[…]